# Vertically Centering and Stretching with CSS

Tags: html, css

I've got a set up like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <header> ... </header>
  <div class="home">
    <div class="inner"> ... </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- /wrapper -->
<footer> ... </footer>
```

The footer is a sticky footer, and I'm using Ryan Fait's sticky footer technique (http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) to achieve this. The header has a fixed height, but I need to somehow get the 'home' div to stretch to the bottom of the 'wrapper' div, and then vertically center div.inner within div.home. I've tried a number of techniques involving relative/absolute positioning and min-height to achieve this but none have worked. Does anyone have experience with a similar problem?

Comment: Have you tried `margin: whatnotpx auto`? Also, please provide a http://jsfiddle.net demo.

Comment: using `width` doesn't work. try `margin-top: x px`  and `margin-bottom: x px`